# Ubuntu 12.10 Server turns monitor black

Tags: server, intel-graphics, monitor, 12.10, intel

After upgrading (and after that I did a clean install) to Ubuntu 12.10 Server my Monitor turns black after choosing Ubuntu in grub. I read several tips about uninstalling proprietary nvidia drivers but my system doesn't have them. 
I'm using an Intel Atom D2700 on its own Board D2700MUD and graphic is onboard (GMA3650).

Ubuntu 12.04 worked fine but as this server is not for production and was set up only a week ago i'd like to use Ubuntu 12.10 and I do not understand this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a newbie but after much frustration and through our friend Google, I managed to find this work around. I tried this on 12.04.01 LTS 64bit server.
It seems to me that this is an issue with intel graphics chipsets.
I found that inserting the nonmodeset string in the Grub boot command solved this problem for me. 
When the server boots up the Grub menu appears for a couple of seconds. Press any key to stop it from completing the boot sequence. You will have the Grub loader screen. Select the first entry then press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit boot commands.You will then have a screen with the boot command sequence. on the 10th line(mines is the 10th line yours might be different after 'yourservername-root' there's 'ro'. Insert the 'nomodeset' command (without apostrophes).
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd> keys together or <kbd>F10</kbd> to complete booting.
It should boot to the user login or command prompt
This is not permanent, if you want it to be permanent you will have to edit the Grub boot command sequence configuration.